# Choose which outputs to open after batch processing in QGIS graphical modeller

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, batch

I created a graphical model with many outputs. I need to test-run it many times to check the effect of some parameter choices on a single output. All other outputs would unnecessarily clutter my workspace.

Running it as a single process, I can mark a checkbox to indicate whether I want a file to be opened or not. How do I set the same specifications in the batch process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the box `Load layers on completion` is unchecked, see screenshot. Be default, it should be unchecked:

[image]

To run it in batch mode and load only one output, add a `Load Layer into Project` algorithm and define the path+filename of one (the first) layer that is created. Then run the model with `Load layers on completion` still unchecked - the one layer defined before will still load.

Tested with the [adapted model created here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/461225/88814), see the added `Load layer into project` algorithm and be sure to select dependency to the last algorithm (the one that normally creates the final output):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The remaining layers would still be saved in my computer unless I specify TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, correct?

Comment: I guess so. You could add a conditional branch so that only one layer is created. Or create a model for testing purpose that only creates the first layer for testing and when it works altering it to include the other outputs as well.